# Why does Peterson's lock fail in this test?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm experimenting with locks that don't require atomic instructions. Peterson's algorithm seemed like the simplest place to start. However, with enough iterations, something goes wrong.

Code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static volatile int _i = 0;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            RunTest();
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void RunTest()
    {
        _i = 0;
        var lockType = new PetersonLock();
        var t1 = new Thread(() => Inc(0, lockType));
        var t2 = new Thread(() => Inc(1, lockType));

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        t1.Join();
        t2.Join();
        Console.WriteLine(_i);
    }

    private static void Inc(int pid, ILock lockType)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                lockType.Request(pid);
                _i++;
                lockType.Release(pid);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}

public interface ILock
{
    void Request(int pid);
    void Release(int pid);
}

public class NoLock : ILock
{
    public void Request(int pid) { }
    public void Release(int pid) { }
}

public class StandardLock : ILock
{
    private object _sync = new object();

    public void Request(int pid)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_sync);
    }

    public void Release(int pid)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_sync);
    }
}

public class PetersonLock : ILock
{
    private volatile bool[] _wantsCs = new bool[2];
    private volatile int _turn;

    public void Request(int pid)
    {
        int j = pid == 1 ? 0 : 1;
        _wantsCs[pid] = true;
        _turn = j;
        while (_wantsCs[j] && _turn == j)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
    }

    public void Release(int pid)
    {
        _wantsCs[pid] = false;
    }
}
```

When I run this, I consistently get < 2,000,000. What's going on?

Comment: Could it be that you did `private int _turn;` and not `private volitile int _turn;` and you are running in to cpu cache issues?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Just tried, it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Add an exception handler (try/catch) to see if you are getting any exceptions.  Program may just be terminating due to  an exception.

Comment: @jdweng no it's not. I just [tired a new version myself](https://gist.github.com/leftler/4e9014938dd42eb72296ad42d7bd92e6) that does that, does multiple itterations, and uses `volitile` everywhere. No exceptions, still get bad output. Condition, if you want to update your question to use the new test version I linked to, feel free.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Updated, thanks

Comment: I see two thinks wrong with the code.  1) first you are not waiting for the processes to finish before you write the results.  So the number that is being displayed is only a partial number. 2) You are only locking the same process from increment _i and not the 2nd process.  It is still possible for both processes to increment _i at the same time and create a conflict.

Comment: The problem here is that `_wantsCs[pid] = true;` and `_turn = j;` is reordered. Try adding a `Thread.MemoryBarrier();` between the two and you should get the right result.

Comment: @jdweng He is joining the threads, which means he will wait until both threads are completely done excecuting. He's also passing in two different `pid` values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is these two statements:

```
_wantsCs[pid] = true;
_turn = j;
```

The memory model of .NET and C# allows these two writes to be reordered.

To force them to not be reordered, add a memory barrier between them:

```
_wantsCs[pid] = true;
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
_turn = j;
```

and you will get the expected output every time.

Note that this very problem is described on the [Wikipedia page for Peterson's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) in the note section (shortened down here, go read the article for the full notes):

> **Notes**
>   ...
>   Most modern CPUs reorder memory accesses to improve execution efficiency (see memory ordering for types of reordering allowed). Such processors invariably give some way to force ordering in a stream of memory accesses, typically through a **memory barrier** instruction. **Implementation of Peterson's and related algorithms on processors which reorder memory accesses generally requires use of such operations to work correctly to keep sequential operations from happening in an incorrect order.**

*(my emphasis)*

Comment: Wow! I've read about this being possible but I've never actually seen it happen. Did you have to look at the disassembly to figure this out, or was there some common pattern you recognized in the source?

Comment: I have seen it before so for me it was easy to spot it as a possible problem, I did not know it was an *actual* problem until I simply tested it. Basically, writing to two variables can be reordered so that other threads can observe the writes to happen in the opposite order.